# How to store results of script url in Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am running a script in the 'head' element of a webpage that is a API call url and returns results in the form of a javascript array. The problem is that the API documentation gives me no reference to what the name of the javascript array is or how to access it, so I have no idea how to use the array in further scripts. I need a way to store the url API call results into a javascript array variable of my own that I can use.

So, is there a way to store the result of the 'head' script as a variable? Thanks, for any help.

`<script lang="javascript" src="https://target_domain/db/
target_dbid?a=API_GenResultsTable&qid=5&jht=1&ticket=auth_ticket">
</script>`

Comment: "The problem is that the API documentation gives me no reference to what the name of the javascript array is or how to access it" — Arrays don't have names, and I find it hard to believe that the documentation doesn't tell you how to access it. We certainly can't tell you because we don't know what API you are talking about.

Comment: Parameters in the URI are delimited by '&', if you split the URI string by '&' you when need to split each returned element by '=' to get the parameter name and it's value, the first element in the array will also need splitting by '?' as this delimits the actual address and port from the parameters.

Comment: `lang="javascript"` — The `lang` attribute should be an ISO language code (e.g. `lang="en"`) describing the *human* language of the content of the element. Putting it on a script element is nonsense. Perhaps you are confusing it with `language` … which should not be used since HTML 4 was released in 1998.

Comment: I admit I have limited experience with API's but feel free to look at the link and tell me how dumb I am. https://help.quickbase.com/api-guide/gen_results_table.html?tocpath=QuickBase%20API%20Call%20Reference%7C_____32

Comment: Well, when reading the docs of your API, we can see that the result is stored in a global function called qdbWrite. Without mentioning this API it was impossible for us  to discover this, like Quentin said.

Comment: It does not return results as an array. It returns a function that when called will write to the document an html `table`.

Comment: If you want to get the data as a javascript array: set the JSA parameter to 1. So replace `jht=1` with `jsa=1` in your request URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the data as a javascript array: set the JSA parameter to 1. So replace `jht=1` with `jsa=1` in your request URL.

When you do this, it will generate a script that stores the result in a global variable called: `qdb_data`.

Note that the GenResultsTable call is intended to generate an HTML table and not to retrieve raw data. To get raw data I'd rather use https://help.quickbase.com/api-guide/do_query.html